# PHP onmouseover change image called from database

Tags: php

```
  echo'<img src="'.$row['filename'].'" onmouseover="this.src='.$row['back_filename'].'" onmouseout="this.src='.$row['filename'].'" />';
```

I'm calling in 2 images from a database using mySql and php, How come this onmousover doesn't work? 
ps. I'm calling a path to the image not storing the image in the database itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
echo'<img src="'.$row['filename'].'" onmouseover="this.src=\''.$row['back_filename'].'\'" onmouseout="this.src=\''.$row['filename'].'\'" />';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing the needed quotes for the inline javascript, you need single quotes `''` around the filename as it is a string, causing whatever the variables hold to be interpreted by javascript as something other than what you expect.

Also use a [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to help with preventing errors caused by misquoting and worrying about escaping quotes.

```
echo <<<END
   <img src="{$row['filename']}" onmouseover="this.src='{$row['back_filename']}'" onmouseout="this.src='{$row['filename']}'" />
END;
```